# Using a wild card with a string function variable in a sumif formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a program that tracks our families spending. It essentially one big sum if calculation. Every month I download our credit card and debit card charges from our bank and have my macros sort and then categorize each charge.

I am trying to make the process easier so my wife and in laws can use the program as well.

I am trying to insert a code that will take a variable that is inputted into a input box and put the said variable in to the sum if equation. The variable will be the name of the charge.  I would like for my wife to be able to input the tag for charge into the input box (the string that triggers the sum if) and then have excel automatically add it to the database of charges I use. This needs a wild card attached to it because some of our monthly charges have really weird computer generated names associated with them.

I have come up with a code so far and by my research it should work....but it doesnt. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub ab_formula()
'
'ab_formula Macro

'



Dim NameExpense As String
Dim TagForExpense As String

NameExpense = InputBox("Enter the name of the new expense", "New Expense", "Type Here", 0, 0)


 TagForExpense = InputBox("Enter the name of the new expense", "TagForExpense", "Type Here", 0, 0)


Range("J23:J2000").Select
ActivateCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SUMIF(C[-8]," * "&TagForExpense&" * ",C[-7])"

Range("I23").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = NameExpense

End Sub
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: tl;dr, but seems like you are multiplying strings `" * "` so fix the quotes.

Comment: something like `Range("J23:J2000").FormulaR1C1 = "SUMIF(C[-8],""*" & TagForExpense & "*"",C[-7])"` without space around `*`

Comment: @Slai Excel automatically spaces out my " around the *. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: @Slai I figure out how to get it to stop inserting the space automatically, but now it gives me a runtime error and says "object required"

Comment: @Slai I figured it out. Thank you for your help! I had to switch activatecell to activecell

Comment: @JosiahHulsey this is not what Slai recommend, you should try avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell`, instead use refernced object as `Range`s , in your code use `Range("J23:J2000").FormulaR1C1` and `Range("I23").FormulaR1C1`